# Como poner primera letra en MAYÚSCULA con CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy tratando de colocar un texto que viene en **MAYÚSCULAS** con la primera letra `mayúscula` y las otras `minúsculas`, el texto no se puede modificar por `js` ni por `html`.
 ¿Existe hay alguna forma con `CSS` de hacer esto posible?

```css
.let p {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="let">
    <p>ESTO ES UNA INFORMACION QUE NECESITO QUE SEA LA PRIMERA LETRA MAYUSCULA Y LAS OTRAS MINUSCULAS</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Deberías pasar el texto a minúscula y luego poner la primera letra como mayúscula utilizando el siguiente selector CSS: [`:first-letter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter).

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```css
.let p {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}

.let p:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="let">
    <p>ESTO ES UNA INFORMACION QUE NECESITO QUE SEA LA PRIMERA LETRA MAYUSCULA Y LAS OTRAS MINUSCULAS</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta me fue útil y resolvió mi problema.

Answer (score 6):

Primero conviertes en **minúsculas** todo el **párrafo**.

```
.let p {
text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

Después aplicas el **uppercase** sólo a la primera letra.

```
.let p::first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, no esta mal me fue útil.

Answer (score 1):

**lowercase**: muestra todo el texto del elemento con letras minúsculas.

**uppercase**: muestra todo el texto del elemento con letras mayúsculas.

**capitalize**: muestra la primera letra de cada palabra en mayúscula y el resto de letras en minúsculas.

**none**: muestra el texto tal y como está escrito, respetando todas las mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: no me sirve esta respuesta, ya he investigado...

Comment: none: muestra el texto tal y como está escrito, respetando todas las mayúsculas y minúsculas. Utilizando esta forma te debería de funcionar.

Comment: Yo también concuerdo con Oswuel debería funcionar con https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-transform.asp

Comment: Si el texto que pone originalmente está todo en mayúsculas, transform: none, va a mostrar todo en mayúsculas...

Answer (score 1):

```css
.let p:first-letter {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.let p:not(first-letter) {
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="let">
    <p>ESTO ES UNA INFORMACION QUE NECESITO QUE SEA LA PRIMERA LETRA MAYUSCULA Y LAS OTRAS MINUSCULAS</p>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text-transform: capitalize !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer que la etiqueta

coja el elemento con los pseudo-elementos, también te puedo recomendar visitar el sitio de www.w3schools.com donde encontraras todos los ejemplos que puedas necesitar sobre paginas web.
Aquí tienes 2 ejemplos para la etiqueta

:

```html
p::first-letter {
    color: #ff0000;
    font-size: xx-large;
}

p::first-line {
    color: #0000ff;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}
```