# ¿Cómo escribir en mayúscula la primera letra de un input de forma predeterminada?

Tags: html, css, input

Como puedo poner en mayúscula la primera letra de un input tipo texto por defecto en html o css?
Existe algun atributo como required que lo haga?

Comment: Buen día, que haz intentado hacer?... Te vendría mejor hacerlo en JS...

Comment: Recuerda agregar lo que trataste o investigaste por favor, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: Puede que quieras que el cambio no sea visual, en ese caso sería una pregunta diferente. El problema es que no podemos saberlo si no lo escribes en la pregunta. Así que sigue siendo duplicado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no conseguí encontrar una forma desde html o css pero dejo la función que cree para JavaScript.

````
```
function textoMayuscula(palabra) {
let mayuscula = palabra[0].toUpperCase();
let palabraSinInicial = palabra.slice(1);
let textoFinal = mayuscula + palabraSinInicial;
return textoFinal;
}
```
````

Lo cree para una lista de tareas por hacer. al introducir un texto en minúscula en el input y enviarlo con un botón, la función toma el valor del input como parámetro, es decir el parámetro "palabra" que se ve arriba. Luego toma la primer letra del string y la hace mayúscula y guarda el resultado en "mayúscula". Después sigue "palabraSinInicial" que toma el resto del string ingresado y lo devuelve sin el primer caracter con "palabra.slice(1)" ya que le indico que comience desde la posición 1 y no desde la posición 0. Por ultimo, sumo ambos resultados en la variable "textoFinal" y la retorno para que se imprima en un li a partir de li.inerText = (Y acá el valor retornado). Espero les sirva, si  me exprese mal pregunten y voy a tratar de responder de la mejor manera posible. Saludos

Comment: Hola Chamilion21, que bueno que lo pudiste solucionar, podrías marcar tu respuesta como aceptada?.

Comment: *no conseguí encontrar una forma desde html o css* -> Literalmente tienes la forma de hacerlo en este mismo StackOverflow, aquí: -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/193649/como-poner-primera-letra-en-may%c3%9ascula-con-css . Te recuerdo que investigar es obligatorio antes de abrir una pregunta, y claramente no has ni utilizado el buscador de SO siquiera.

Comment: @Benito-B El problema real es que la naturaleza de un `input` es ingresar un dato para ser utilizado "en algo" (es una entrada como el nombre lo dice), La respuesta que tu enlazas cambia la primera letra a mayúsculas en un div, que para ese caso puede servir, pero para un `input` solo genera un cambio cosmético no afectando el `value` el cual sigue retornado el valor original. Es por eso que esa respuesta no aplica

Comment: @Yussef también lo pensé pero la pregunta dice ***Como puedo poner en mayúscula la primera letra de un input tipo texto por defecto en html o css***. O sea, no le interesa que el cambio sea real y no visual.

Comment: @Mateo Puede ser que el usuario estaba buscando, en principio, un método sin JS, como `required` que antes de HTML5 había que hacerlo con javascript y ahora se hace con HTML. Al no encontrar esta forma ni por HTML ni por CSS, se vio obligado a usar JS, por que justamente es la única forma de cambiar el `value`.

Comment: @Yussef Estoy de acuerdo contigo en que es muy posible que eso sea lo que buscaba de un inicio. Pero viéndolo desde el punto de vista de la comunidad, la pregunta no está correctamente redactada. Un usuario que quiera encontrar la manera de *obtener el valor de un input con la primera inicial en mayúscula* no va a encontrar esta respuesta. Además, habla de "Escribirlo", no de "recoger" o "usar" el valor... en el estado actual, la pregunta no es útil ni las respuestas responden realmente a la pregunta planteada...